# If $F:\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ if of class $C^{1}$ ...

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm studying differentiation and came across this question: If $F:\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is of class $C^{1}$ such that $\Vert f^{\prime}(x)v\Vert \geqslant 2\Vert v\Vert$. Then F is a diffeomorphism of  $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. I can not take the condition of $F$ to show that $F$ is injective. If you could help me, thanks.

Comment: Traducelo a ingles que no te van contestar!!!

Comment: Peruano???? Donde estudias?? Saludos de otro Peruano! que milagro encontrar un peruano en este sitio....

Comment: Si, peruano estudio en San Marcos.

Comment: Que anho vas???

Comment: Este año termino, también eres san marquino?

Comment: No, yo vivo en nueva york ahora, estudio en la universidad de stony brook. todavia me falta un ano a mi para acabar... Que libro usas para topologia?

Comment: James Munkres, usualmente.